# How do I fix the Laravel queue error: "Instances of Aws\Sqs\SqsClient cannot be serialized"?

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs

I have created a data migrator using the Laravel v8.x queue system and some batched jobs. For the queue backend, I am using AWS SQS. Without changing any of the code, one day jobs started failing randomly with the following error:

```
/var/www/data-migrator/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php:275
Instances of Aws\Sqs\SqsClient cannot be serialized
```

The stack trace points to the following line of code which is unchanged:

```
})->onConnection($queue_conn)->dispatch();
```

(Previous lines of code just set up the batch, the `then` callback, and the `catch` callback.)

Over time, the number of these random failures increased until all jobs failed, again without any changes to the code. What is the cause of this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that AWS decided to change how its infrastructure and SDK work so that prod deployments that we thought were safe can randomly break. The solution is simple:

```
$ composer update
$ git add composer.lock
$ git commit -m 'update because bezos'
$ git push
```

And on the prod instance(s):

```
$ git pull
$ composer install
$ php artisan queue:restart
```

This is the second time in a 12 month period that this has happened, and I could not find anything about this error anywhere, so I decided to share the solution here.